# Connect javascript with localhost server but page provided by other server

Tags: javascript, php, post, websocket

On one side is a web server in localhost.

On the other hand there is a online web server that supplies the "example.html" page to browser in localhost.

What I want to do is connect the javascript code that is in example.html with localhost server.

The problem is that because of security mechanisms of Javascript, you can not send a POST request to a server / domain different from that delivered the page.

1)Is there a way to send POST requests to another different server that the supplies page?

2)With WebSocket would be possible to do this or else have the same problem?

3)Is there any other technology to do this?

Comment: How about you just iframe example.html? If not you will need to emulate all te js endpoints on localhost and parse them through to the remote site in php

Comment: What do you mean "connect the javascript code with localhost?" elaborate, please?

Comment: Send command/data like POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know of javascript but you can do it with php by using `curl`. You should use the code below

```
<?php
$url = THE_URL_TO_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND_POST_DATA;

$fields = array(
        'PARAM1'=>$_POST['PARAM1'],
        'PARAM2'=>$_POST['PARAM2']
);

$postvars='';
$sep='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{
        $postvars.= $sep.urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
        $sep='&';
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that communication occurs from php, that is from the server side, not okay. Because the local server is on a private network without port forwarding and is thus not visible. Only  can see through a web browser that is localhost itself.